# Trouble installing openjdk8 after accepting license agreement

Tags: apt, java, dpkg

Trying to download openjdk8, I ran the command

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless
```

The package configuration told me to agree to the license agreement on [oracle.com](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html), which I believe I did.

Then I pressed okay, and this happened:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 unable to install updated status of 'shared-mime-info': No such file or directory
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: *(...) which I believe I did* but it's not a matter of "believe", you either did it or didn't. If the license appeared in the terminal you would have to press TAB, then use the arrow keys to navigate the options and enter to confirm. Is this what you did?

Comment: You aught to agree to license on the terminal not at oracle, I believe.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/102480/sudo-apt-get-upgrade-fails-due-to-shared-mime-info-postinst-error